# Qt commercial license

Tags: qt, licensing

We are wondering if someone has experience with the way Qt license works. We want to develop a closed source, proprietary license  application (with static linking to Qt libraries), which will be installed to several computers (> 100). We might consider purchasing a commercial license, but we are not sure whether the license fee is:

1. per developer
2. per workstation
3. per company
4. per installation
5. per team
6. anything else?

Anyone has experience in this area?

Comment: Why not contact them directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I used it, eons ago, the license was "per developer".
This has changed now, as far as I can tell. Take a look at this: 
[QT commercial vs. non-commercial license for beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095136/qt-commercial-vs-non-commercial-license-for-beginner) and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945612/qt-lgpl-licencing-for-a-free-application-with-closed-source